# How to merge 2 objects in java

Tags: java

I want to save JSON data in dynamodb DB table as a column name with the corresponding value, i,e:

```
Date = 2017-06-12
Cash Buyer = 5751.0
```

To push the data into dynamodb table I need the JSON to be in the form of `List<Map<String,Object>>` Format.

The json data looks like this:

```
{"dataset":{"id":19701916,"column_names":["Date","Cash Buyer","Cash Seller \u0026 Settlement","3-months Buyer","3-months Seller","15-months Buyer","15-months Seller","Dec 1 Buyer","Dec 1 Seller","Dec 2 Buyer","Dec 2 Seller","Dec 3 Buyer","Dec 3 Seller"],"frequency":"daily","type":"Time Series","premium":false,"limit":null,"transform":null,"column_index":null,"start_date":"2012-01-03","end_date":"2017-06-14","data":[["2017-06-14",5684.0,5684.5,5715.0,5717.0,null,null,5780.0,5790.0,5790.0,5800.0,5790.0,5800.0],["2017-06-13",5658.0,5659.0,5692.0,5693.0,null,null,5750.0,5760.0,5765.0,5775.0,5760.0,5770.0],["2017-06-12",5751.0,5752.0,5782.0,5783.0,null,null,5835.0,5845.0,5850.0,5860.0,5845.0,5855.0]"database_id":13206}}
```

This JSON Data has column name in one list and thier corresponding value in another Array List.I am getting this JSON Data from an API.
Can someone help me in this?

Comment: Do I understand correct, that you want a json like that: `{"columnName1": "value1", "columnName2": "value2",... }`?

Comment: Yes exactly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `json` is invalid (you can validate it [here](https://jsonlint.com/)). Once validated, you can use any Json serialisation tool to read and transform it. Below is an example with Jackson (documentation [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs)):

```
//Deserialisation
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> dataMap = (Map<String, Object>) mapper.readValue("{\"dataset\":{\"id\":19701916,\"column_names\":[\"Date\",\"Cash Buyer\",\"Cash Seller Settlement\",\"3-months Buyer\",\"3-months Seller\",\"15-months Buyer\",\"15-months Seller\",\"Dec 1 Buyer\",\"Dec 1 Seller\",\"Dec 2 Buyer\",\"Dec 2 Seller\",\"Dec 3 Buyer\",\"Dec 3 Seller\"],\"frequency\":\"daily\",\"type\":\"Time Series\",\"premium\":false,\"limit\":null,\"transform\":null,\"column_index\":null,\"start_date\":\"2012-01-03\",\"end_date\":\"2017-06-14\",\"data\":[[\"2017-06-14\",5684.0,5684.5,5715.0,5717.0,null,null,5780.0,5790.0,5790.0,5800.0,5790.0,5800.0],[\"2017-06-13\",5658.0,5659.0,5692.0,5693.0,null,null,5750.0,5760.0,5765.0,5775.0,5760.0,5770.0],[\"2017-06-12\",5751.0,5752.0,5782.0,5783.0,null,null,5835.0,5845.0,5850.0,5860.0,5845.0,5855.0]]}}", Map.class);
System.out.println(transform((Map<String, Object>)dataMap.get("dataset")));


//Transformation

private static List<Map<String,Object>> transform (Map<String, Object> dataMap){
    List<Map<String,Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> columns = (List<String>) dataMap.get("column_names");
    List<List<Object>> data = (List<List<Object>>) dataMap.get("data");

    for(List<Object> dataElement : data){
        Map<String, Object> element = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < dataElement.size() ; i++){
            element.put(columns.get(i), dataElement.get(i));
        }
        result.add(element);
    }

    return result;
}
```

P.S. This is just an example using `Map` and `List`. You can create Pojos and use those to get rid of casting.